# PPM to JPEG/JPG conversion for Python 3.4.1

Tags: python, jpeg, ppm

Does anyone know of any way to convert a ppm file to a jpeg/jpg using python 3.4.1 specifically? I've looked around and can only find solutions for previous version of python.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) module. The following should work:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("sweet_pic.ppm")
im.save("sweet_pic.jpg")
```

Read through the [tutorial](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html) for more information.

Comment: Documention says it supports 3.4, but not 3.4.1?

Comment: @star compatibility is by minor version (python versions are `major.minor.micro`, so 3.4.1 is minor version 3.4). So, if it says 3.4, it'll work with 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, etc.

Comment: Didn't work because i had too many channels. I figured it out though using cv2 and PIL

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenCV

```
i = cv.imread('im0001.ppm')
cv.imwrite('im0001.jpg',i)
```

Comment: Tried that makes the image be very very bright. Any ideas?

Comment: Alright i figured it out i converted the files to png with cv2 and then to jpg with Pillow `from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image_path")
im.convert('RGB').save("image_name.jpg","JPEG") #this converts png image as jpeg`