# Is it possible to convert a ppm file from p3 to p6 or use pillow lib to open a ppm p3 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Is it possible to convert a ppm file from p3 to p6 or use pillow lib to open and read a ppm p3 file?

I actually have ppm p3 files and trying to convert them to jpg using pillow lib, but unfortunately, it doesn't read p3 files only p6.

Any idea abou how can i get solve this?

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("sweet_pic.ppm")
im.save("sweet_pic.jpg")
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937263/8692977

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably outsource this task to ImageMagick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `P3` **NetPBM** file is ASCII (textual, and larger) whereas a `P6` file is binary (and smaller). If you use **ImageMagick** the difference is made by specifying the compression:

```
# convert to P6 (binary)
convert image.ppm result.ppm

# convert to P3 (ASCII)
convert image.ppm -compress none result.ppm
```

The default, as usual, is to go to the smallest file type, i.e. `P6`, so you don’t need to do anything for that - as in first example above.