# How to convert PPM image file to JPG or PNG using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I have made a script which makes a valid ppm file which when opened using a ppm viewer is working properly.

But I don't want my users to install a ppm viewer to view their output images instead I want it to be converted to a global file format like a JPG/JPEG or PNG.

Comment: You need to help the community understand what you have done so far to try and resolve the issue. That will guide them to getting you a solution that might be acceptable for you. Also, look for existing question like this, such as the one answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937143/ppm-to-jpeg-jpg-conversion-for-python-3-4-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PPM to JPEG/JPG conversion for Python 3.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937143/ppm-to-jpeg-jpg-conversion-for-python-3-4-1)

Comment: Please click [edit] and show the first 3 lines of your PPM file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module for python.

```
from PIL import Image
with Image.open("your_ppm_file.ppm") as im:
     im.save("your_jpg_file.jpg")
```

Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: This is not working :(